# How to set the value of a form element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe, mootools

I have a simple form like this one:

```
<form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<p>UPLOAD FILE: <input type="file" name="file1"> <br /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
<input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="">
</form>
```

I have to set the value of the hidden field to an email like "email@email.com".
I can obtain this value from adding a querystring parameter by external iframe like:

```
<iframe name="email@email.com" src="index.html?email=email@email.com">
```

Ok. But how can I set value="" to value="email@email.com"?
I know have to use javascript, but I dunno how to deal with the var.

Comment: You could also fill it in on the server side if you want - you could get your index.html to use some server-side processing, take the email parameter and insert it into the field when you generate the form. But it's easy enough to do this with JavaScript too.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) to extract the query string values. Some of the solutions may be a bit over-the-top for what you need but they're robust too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('Id').value='new value';
```

**answer to comment:**
try this:

```
<input type="" name="email" id="email">

<iframe id="frm" name="email@email.com" src="index.html?email=email@email.com">
</iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById('email').value = document.getElementById('frm').name;
</script>
```

then you can change adopt it. change type to hidden and etc.

Comment: Ok it works but this value is dynamic.
I have to extract it from the querystring parameter by external iframe.
This is my problem :/

Answer (score 2):

If your script is executed from the document inside the iframe, you can do this :

```
var getUrlParameter = function(name, defaultValue) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( document.location.href );
    if( results == null ) return defaultValue;
    else return decodeURIComponent(results[1]);
};

document.getElementById('email').value=getUrlParameter('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've labeled this question as jQuery You can use `$('#Id').val('new value');` But don't forget to add jQuery Library.

Comment: Told other user that the var is dynamic.
I dunno how can I deal with the val('new value').